# repository configuration process instantiation failed No deployments available for org.guvnor:guvnor-asset-mgmt-project:latest

Tags: drools, kie, drools-guvnor, guvnor

i installed drools in this configuration on a windows server:

- wildfly-8.2.1.Final
- kie-drools-wb-distribution-wars-6.4.0.Final-wildfly8.war
- kie-server-distribution-6.4.0.Final.zip

I get the error "repository configuration process instantiation failed No deployments available for org.guvnor:guvnor-asset-mgmt-project:latest" creating a new repository:

- drools workbench
- "Authoring" - Administration
- "Repositories" - "New repository"

[new repository 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ke3UP.jpg)
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXdcK.jpg)

What can I do?

Thank you!
Michael

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use this setup:
- windows server
- wildfly-10.1.0.Final
- kie-drools-wb-6.5.0.Final-wildfly10
- kie-server-distribution-6.5.0.Final